# Android app configuration set to rtl but conflict start with end

Tags: android, visa

I'm using RTL in my android app every thing going well until i use Visa sdk 
it change the layout direction 
i think because they are using chrome webview client but i can't solve it

Comment: If you using third party SDK then RTL support work if provider provide support for that properly.

Comment: but why it change the layout direction in my application !